# mouse issues -I get cursor but no action on click 14.04 mimimal desktop esxi open vm tools desktop

Tags: 14.04, mouse, vmware

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS server on a vm on ESXi 5.5. I've installed minimal desktop then also installed `open-vm-tools` and `open-vm-tools-desktop`.

The mouse cursor is visible, but nothing happens when I click left or right.

What could be happening here?